# Combining two relative Uris

Tags: c#, .net, uri

I need to combine two relative Uris, e.g. `../mypath/` and `myimage.png` to create `../mypath/myimage.png`. They are not paths to files on disk so `Path.Combine` is not appropriate (they are relative paths to resources for a web page). `new Uri` throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because the base uri is relative (not absolute).

Do I have any options other than checking for a trailing slash and then combining the paths myself?

EDIT:

Here is a test case that demonstrates that Path.Combine will not work for the case when the first url does not already contain a trailing slash:

```
// The first case fails with result "../testpath\resource.png"
[TestCase("../testpath", "resource.png", "../testpath/resource.png")] 
[TestCase("../testpath/", "resource.png", "../testpath/resource.png")]
public void TestPathCombine(string path, string resourceName, string expectedResult) {
    string result = Path.Combine(path, resourceName);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine relative baseUri with relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925468/combine-relative-baseuri-with-relative-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use path.combine as it is for physcial path so it might confuse you with slashes. You can make your own function of Uri combine. Checking slash at the end and append it to next one.

Can URI constructor with two argument help?

```
new Uri(Uri baseUri, string relativeUri)
```

Comment: As I stated in the post using that new URI constructor fails with an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because the baseUri is relative. Creating my own function really seems like my only option.

Comment: I think it is the best way to do it. Take help of VirtualPathUtility class. It has combine function but i am not sure if it exactly fit your requirement. But it has functions that might help to make one. e.g. AppendTrailingSlash and AppendTrailingSlash

Comment: VirtualPathUtility.AppendTrailingSlash plus simple string concatenation solves this question. However in the end I decided to require and document that the trailing slash was required for the base path in the first place.

Comment: Great Lawrence. And it would be useful if you edit your post and put the function here as it might help people who visit this post :P

Answer (score 8):

If your second part is (like in my own case) really a file name without any escaping (and as such may contain invalids chars for an url), here is the solution I have ended up with:

```
VirtualPathUtility.Combine(
    VirtualPathUtility.AppendTrailingSlash(relativeUri), 
    Uri.EscapeDataString(fileName));
```

Beware that this solution will not support a full uri (with scheme, host, port): it will throw an exception with a full uri.
Thanks to Manish Pansiniya for [mentioning System.Web.VirtualPathUtility](/questions/4390697/combining-two-relative-uris/12518415#comment4785374_4390976).

In addition, as my file name was in fact a partial file path (some folder names followed by file name), rather than calling directly System.Uri.EscapeDataString, I have call the following function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert a partial file path to a partial url path.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="partialFilePath">The partial file path.</param>
/// <returns>A partial url path.</returns>
public static string ConvertPartialFilePathToPartialUrlPath(
    string partialFilePath)
{
    if (partialFilePath == null)
        return null;
    return string.Join("/", 
        partialFilePath.Split('/', '\\')
            .Select(part => Uri.EscapeDataString(part)));
}
```

(Requires using System.Linq for .Select and fx4 for the used string.Join overload.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Uri` constructor that takes a base and a relative part to do the combination - but note that the behavior will possibly not be what you expect.   The `Uri` class will see the end part of your base as either a "directory" or a "file" (to put it in path terms).  If it sees the end as a file, that will get removed.

For example, combining `http://server/something/` with `resource.png` will give you `http://server/something/resource.png`.

Now omit the trailing slash: combine `http://server/something` with `resource.png` and get `http://server/resource.png`.

This makes sense if you think of it as starting with a base Uri of `http://server/something.png` and asking for the relative uri `resource.png`: `http://server/something.png/resource.png` isn't what you're looking for.

If you ALWAYS know that they should be appended, you need to make sure that the base ends with a slash before combining.

Comment: The question is how to "combine two relative Uris".