# Joining Url and relative file path into valid Uri?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, uri

I have kind of a funky question- given the uri `http://localhost`, and a relative file path of `virtualdirectory\\path\\to\\my\\file.html`, how can I merge these into a valid Url which should be `http://localhost/virtualdirectory/path/to/my/file.html`?

I'm using Web.API and a client search to see if a static html file exists in a virtual directory on the server.  The client requests the search with jQuery, the Web.API controller does the searching on the local virtual directory.  If the file does exist, the controller needs to return a valid Url to the client so the client can view that static html file.

If that makes sense. :)

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925468/combine-relative-baseuri-with-relative-path

Comment: Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681052/get-absolute-url-from-relative-path-refactored-method which has a highly rated, accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Uri(new Uri("http://localhost/"), "virtualdirectory\\path\\to\\my\\file.html".Replace("\\","/"));
```

Comment: Just an interesting note: the code works even without `Replace()` call.

Comment: @SergeyBrunov  That doesn't surprise me. The Uri class tries to do a lot of magic.  Good to know though.